# How to get rid of "NU3012 Package xunit, author primary signature found a chain building issue, certificate is revoked" error?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, xunit

I have the following issue that I can't get rid of...

NU3012 Package 'xunit*' from source "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json": The author primary signature found a chain building issue: Revoked: The certificate is revoked"

[image: Text]

Could you help please?

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out. For unknown reason xUnit certificate was in "Untrusted certificates" folder.
Moving it back to Trusted root folder got the error disappeared.

[image]